# IOS app initiate tracking when app is in the background based on a countdown timer

Tags: ios, iphone, timer, cllocationmanager

I have an IOS app that initiates location services based on a countdown timer which then sends the data to a server.  I would like that app to be able to initiate that while in the background, but have been told by a developer that's not possible.  I'd like to know if that's true, and if it is technically true if there there are some other 'tricks' to get the app to start it's tracking in the background.

Comment: You can track continually in the background and decide whether you want to send the update to the server based on the current time, but you can't start tracking at a certain time when the app is already suspended.  Continual background tracking can impact battery life.

Comment: Would a strategy to do this with minimal power use be to set tracking to be with the least accuracy, and not send updates to the server (so minimal power used) and at the time that the timer hits '0' then start tracking with a desired accuracy and sending updates to the server?

Comment: maybe, but timers don't run when your app is in the background, so you would need to wait for the first location update after your deadline time and start tracking then. Depending on whether the user is moving the update could come a significant time after th deadline.

Comment: They will be moving in my use case - it's a race.  So, when the first update comes after the deadline time (which will be some few minutes before the race start) I can switch to sending the data and to a more accurate location, right?

Comment: Yes, that could work; You would need to test it to see if it meets your needs.  Without GPS the user may have to move several hundred meter s to trigger and update.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think that if I start this 10 min before the start there will be enough motion to trigger it.  I'll have to test it, but I don't have a lot of options otherwise since IOS removed timers grrrrr (this is so easy on Android).